# Entity Framework Code first migration foreign key relationship between multiple database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Consider two tables -

1. `Users` in Database1 (DB1; columns: UserId, UserName
2. `Roles` in Database2 (DB2); columns:- RoleId, RoleName

Now add `roleId` in `users` table, referencing `Roles.RoleId` in in DB2.

**Question**: how can I implement this in using Entity Framework code first migration?

Comment: Most concrete database systems I know will **NOT** support cross-database foreign keys - you cannot establish a db-enforced FK relationship between two separate databases

Comment: What I do is create a view in DB1 that points to the table in DB2.